# Client - Server socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am begginer with Java, so what I need to get this work?
I make classes, into this I added main method where I paste this code, but this isn't work.
In server class gives me some errors about a finally variable. I dont understand nothing.

**Client Class**

```
    //Creating the client socket:
    Socket socket = new Socket ();

    //Binding to the local socket address:
    InetAddress localIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName ("0.0.0.0");
    int localIpPort = 0;
    SocketAddress localSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress (localIpAddress, localIpPort);
    socket.bind (localSocketAddress);

    //Connecting to the remote socket address:
    InetAddress remoteIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName ("localhost");
    int remoteIpPort = 20000;
    SocketAddress remoteSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress (remoteIpAddress, remoteIpPort);
    socket.connect (remoteSocketAddress);

    //Receiving and/or sending data through inbound and outbound streams:
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream ()));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (socket.getOutputStream ()));

    String request = "Hello";
    writer.write (request);
    writer.newLine ();
    // Do not forget to flush
    writer.flush ();

    // Reading the response
    String response = reader.readLine ();

    //Shutting-down the inbound and outbound streams:
    socket.shutdownInput ();
    socket.shutdownOutput ();

    //Closing the socket:
    socket.close ();
    [...]
```

**Server Class**

```
    //Creating the server socket:
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket ();

    //Binding to the local socket address -- this is the one the clients should be connecting to:
    InetAddress localIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName ("0.0.0.0");
    int localIpPort = 20000;
    SocketAddress localSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress (localIpAddress, localIpPort);
    socket.bind (localSocketAddress);

    while (true) {

            //For each connection accepting a client socket, and:
            Socket client = socket.accept ();

            // Starting a new Thread for each client
            new Thread () {

                    public void run () {
                            try {
                                    //Receiving and/or sending data;
                                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (client.getInputStream ()));
                                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (client.getOutputStream ()));

                                    // Reading the request
                                    String request = reader.readLine ();
                                    // Write the response
                                    String response = "Welcome";
                                    writer.write(response);
                                    writer.newLine();
                                    // Do not forget to flush!
                                    writer.flush();

                                    client.close ();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            };
    }

    //Closing the server socket;
    socket.close ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Socket client = socket.accept ();` into `final Socket client = socket.accept ();`.

Comment: Last error is socket.close() is unreachable code? In Server Class

Comment: Of course. `while (true) {…` forms an infinite loop. So putting a `close` after that loop makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an anonymous inner class, and to access variables (like client) from the containing scope, they have to be declared final.

the final keyword  means you won't be able to reassign the variable afterwards, but I don't think that'll be a problem.

to illustrate:

here...

```
new Thread () {

                public void run () {
                        try {
```

you are subclassing Thread on the fly, implementing the run method from the runnable interface. This is an anonymous class because you haven't declared anew class that you can reuse somewhere else - it is a one-off subclass of Thread, and being anonymous, you cna only use variables from outside the class definition if they are final.